# Windows detecting wrong driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers

My sound card is onboard (MSI-MS 7693), and always will be detected automatically by windows after re-installing windows (Detected true driver: RealTek), its been a week every time i power my pc on, after login to windows, it starts detecting wrong audio device (it detects nVidia High Definition Audio instead of RealTek) and try to install it and every time fails, and result is i have no sound! what is problem and how can i solve it? re-installing windows is a real mass and i try to avoid!

Comment: Next time you load your machine I assume Windows will detect the incorrect hardware - when it does, go into device manager and see if the incorrect item is listed and try to disable it.

Comment: i disabled them many times and every time after restart every thing starts again just like the last time,

Comment: yes, my chip is up to date

Comment: there is no other sound card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by installing NVidia Graphic Card update, it was included with HD Audio Driver and made conflicts with previous installed driver.
I restored my windows to before installing that update and everything works fine.

Comment: I think the nVidia HD Audio Driver is required when you're using HDMI and want sound to be passed through that. When I recently moved a PC from using speakers to outputting sound through a TV, I found this driver had to be installed otherwise you ended up with no sound.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the button down right on the taskbar, where you can set the volume. Open, and click on "mixer". In the "Device"-area, you can click on this dropdown menu and choose between the outputs. Choose your Realtek driver there.

Comment: in this situation this button does not open the Mixer, it opens Troubleshooter.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to RnBandCrunk answer, but I suggest right clicking on the speaker symbol in the task bar (near the clock) and selecting playback devices:

[image]

Under the playback tab you will see what is available - select the device you want to use and set it as default.

[image]

Comment: there is no audio device listed, every time windows detects wrong device and try to install it, it fails!

Comment: Are you installing the driver from your machine or automatically from the internet? If you haven't, download the driver to your machine and when you install it, browse for it and install it manually.

Comment: i tried both ways, automatically and manually! just nothing happened

Comment: Did you download driver from http://uk.msi.com/service/download/driver-2584.html

Comment: yes, i downloaded the driver too, there was no difference at the end!

Comment: I wonder if there is a hardware issue - this is a very odd problem, I'd actually be tempted to buy a new sound card (or at least borrow one) to see if you can get round it; I'm sorry, I don't think I can help any more.

Comment: i installed a windows temporarily on another hard and everything just worked normally, correct and with no problem. so its not an hardware issue. thanks for all your tries Dave.

Comment: @Armin if you think you've solved it, feel free to answer your own question. I assume this means it's Windows having a 'senior moment' etc and that maybe a windows repair, a system restore or a reformat will solve it?

Comment: sure i will do, but unfortunately its look like i have a dead end!! my system checkpoints will restore my pc to when i loose many configuration and apps of mine, so its better to re-install windows (something that im trying to avoid). System repair will rewrite many things that will make many configs nonfunctional too, by the way experience tell me most problems will remain!!